# .ONESHELL not working properly in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets):***

> `.ONESHELL`
>   
>   
>     If `.ONESHELL` is mentioned as a target, then when a target is
>     built all lines of the recipe will be given to a single invocation
>     of the shell rather than each line being invoked separately (*note
>     Recipe Execution: Execution.).

***So, a makefile, like:***

```make
.ONESHELL :

all ::
    echo 'foo
    bar'
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
$ make
echo 'foo
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: [all] Error 2 (ignored)
```

***Trying, with almost the same makefile, but adding a `-` prefix to the recipe, to ignore errors, as [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html#Errors):***

> To ignore errors in a recipe line, write a '-' at the beginning of
>   the line's text (after the initial tab).  The '-' is discarded before
>   the line is passed to the shell for execution.

***The makefile, like:***

```make
.ONESHELL :

all ::
    -echo 'foo
    bar'
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
$ make
echo 'foo
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: [all] Error 2 (ignored)
bar'
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: [all] Error 2 (ignored)
```

Why?

Comment: Which version of GNU `make` are you using?  (What does `make --version` have to say?)

Comment: And please go back to the other questions in your recent sequence and insert the version information into the question.  Now that there's one definite version-dependency, it becomes crucial to document that you're using the old (but very widespread) version of GNU Make.

Answer (score 34):

GNU Make 3.81 does not support `.ONESHELL`, but 3.82 does.

```
$ /usr/gnu/bin/make --version
GNU Make 3.82
$ /usr/bin/gmake --version
GNU Make 3.81
$ cat gnu.mk
.ONESHELL:

all:
    echo 'foo' "$$$$"
    echo 'bar' "$$$$"
$ /usr/bin/gmake -f gnu.mk
echo 'foo' "$$"
foo 3100
echo 'bar' "$$"
bar 3101
$ /usr/gnu/bin/make -f gnu.mk
echo 'foo' "$$"
echo 'bar' "$$"
foo 3103
bar 3103
$
```

I deduce that you're using GNU Make 3.81 from 2006 (or possibly an earlier version, but 3.80 is from 2002); 3.82 is from 2010.  The current version is 4.1 from 2014. The online documentation applies to the current version.  While lots of the material also applies to older versions, not all of it does.

I also observe that the original `makefile` with the single single quote on the first line and another on the second seems to cause trouble even with GNU Make 3.82.  However, when the lines are each OK, it does seem to work.  That's a bit puzzling.  And, now I've also installed GNU Make 4.1 (I'd already got it downloaded, but hadn't built it), it too has problems with the `bust.mk` file below.

```
$ cat bust.mk
.ONESHELL:

all:
    echo 'foo
    bar' "$$$$"
$ /usr/gnu/bin/make -f bust.mk
echo 'foo
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [all] Error 2
$
```

I'm not sure I understand how GNU Make gets confused by that.  It might be worth filing a bug for it.  OTOH, I'm not sure I'm going to get worried about it, either.  But you'll need to take this odd behaviour into account in your future testing.

Comment: Also, with modern shells and modern scripting languages, there are plenty of portable, readable, maintainable workarounds which don't require physical newlines to be embedded in your command line. `sed $'s\nbalh\nblah\n'` (assuming Bash) or `perl -pe 's\nbalh\nblah\n'`

Comment: Tested with GNU make 4.3 and it still is buggy. If there is a `SHELL=/bin/bash` or any other shell than `SHELL=/bin/sh` then the bust.mk works as expected. Also replacing `echo` with `printf '%s\n'` works. Note that `echo` is one of the commands make knows is builtin to sh.

Comment: > GNU Make 3.81 does not support .ONESHELL, but 3.82 does.
WAAAAAT :facepalm:

$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81

Thanks!

Comment: FYI for Mac users: up to at least 10.14 (Mojave), `usr/bin/make` is version 3.81.

Comment: Up to Max OS X 10.15.7 (Catalina), the `/usr/bin/make` is of version 3.81.

Comment: Big Sur (11.6.7) still 3.81

Comment: Ventura (13.0) still 3.81

Comment: The likely reason for sticking with 3.81 is that GNU Make 4.x is licensed under GPL 3.0 or later, whereas GNU Make 3.81 is licensed with GPL 2 or later.  I believe this is also why Bash is still a 3.x version (not 4.x or 5.x), and why `zsh` (licenced with a variant of the MIT licence) is now the preferred shell on macOS.